# Metric math alarms: How can I use a for_each expression to loop over metrics within a dynamic block?

Tags: foreach, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create dynamic metric math alarms, that are configurable with a JSON.

I am struggling with looping over the metric alarm with a for_each expression as this is a loop within a loop.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "Percentage_Alert" {
  for_each = var.percentage_error_details
  locals { alarm_details = each.value }
  alarm_name          = "${terraform.workspace}-${each.key}"
  comparison_operator = local.alarm_details["Comparison_Operator"]
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  threshold           = local.alarm_details["Threshold"]
  
  metric_query {
    id          = "e1"
    expression  = local.alarm_details["Expression"]
    label       = local.alarm_details["Label"]
    return_data = "true"
  }
  dynamic "metric_query" {
    for metric in each.value["Metrics"]{
      id = metric.key 

      metric_name = metric.value
      period      = local.alarm_details["Period"]
      stat        = local.alarm_details["Statistic"]
      namespace   = local.full_namespace
      unit        = "Count"
    }
    }
}
```

And this is the sample JSON

```
{
  "locals": {
      "Name": {
        "Name": "metric_math",
        "Metrics": {
          "m1": "Sucess",
          "m2": "Failure"
        },
        "Expression": "100*(m2/(m1+m2))",
        "Threshold" : 1,
        "Period": 25,
        "Priority": "critical",
        "Statistic": "Sum",
        "Label": "label",
        "Comparison_Operator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
        }  
    }
  }
```

And this is the error message i'm getting:

```
Error: Invalid block definition

On ../modules/cloudwatch/metriclogfilter/main.tf line 89: Either a quoted
string block label or an opening brace ("{") is expected here.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This might be easier to answer if your question formed a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @HannahW, can you let us know where `line 89` is in your terraform code / main.tf  and post the offending line?